# Ejecutar archivo .bat desde un JOB en oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-11g, .bat

Estoy intentando crear un JOB desde Oracle 11g que ejecute un archivo .bat en mi servidor.

El archivo .bat contiene algo simple

```
@echo off
echo Hola Mundo
pause
```

Y mi JOB lo programo de la siguiente manera.

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB(
    job_name        => 'TEST_BAT',
    job_type        => 'EXECUTABLE',
    job_action      => 'host cmd /c D:\Reporte\TEST.bat',
    start_date      => SYSTIMESTAMP,
    repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY; BYHOUR=12; BYMINUTE=0; BYSECOND=0',
    enabled         => TRUE
  );
END;
```

Lo ejecute con el usuario SYS, por si era tema de permisos, pero aún asi no funciona.

Este es el log del JOB

```
ORA-27370: fallo del esclavo del trabajo al iniciar un trabajo de tipo EXECUTABLE
ORA-27300: operación dependiente del sistema operativo: fallo de accessing job scheduler service con el estado: 109
ORA-27301: mensaje de error del sistema operativo: Ha terminado la canalización.
ORA-27302: el fallo se ha producido en: sjsec 9
ORA-27303: información adicional: Ha terminado la canalización.
```

Agradezco a todos por su atención.

No se si estoy programando mal mi JOB, agradezco su ayuda

Comment: ¿Por qué no lanzar un script de SQL desde el [*Programador de Tareas*](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programador_de_tareas_de_Windows)?

Comment: ¿Te fijaste en la estructura del job en [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30405081)?

Comment: Si, lo intente de esa manera llamando en el  job_action => 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe' y luego pasando por parametro la ruta donde esta el archivo .bat, pero al consultar el log, me sigue arrojando el mismo error que adjunte